# Vue JS: Open Menu Component with Button, Close with Click Outside of Menu

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, custom-directive

*`Vue JS 2.6.10`*

I have read a variety of SO posts about how to create a custom directive so that you can detect a click outside of a popup menu so you can close it. I can't quite get it to work because I have a button that opens the menu and clicking it fires the "close" behavior.

Here's my main view **`Logbook.vue`** that has the button that opens the menu:
[image]

```
// --- Logbook.vue ---
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Logbook',
  components:{
    Years
  },
  methods:{
    clickYears: function(){
      this.$refs.Years.show = true
    }
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <div id="current-year">
    <a href="#year" ref="yearButton" v-on:click.prevent="clickYears">{{ currentYear }}</a>
    <Years ref="Years" v-on:selectYear="yearSelected" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is the menu component **`Years.vue`** that opens when you click the button:
[image]

```
//--- Years.vue ---
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'

//Custom directive to handle clicks outside of this component
Vue.directive('click-outside', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    window.event = function (event) {
      if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
        vnode.context[binding.expression](event)
      }
    };
    document.body.addEventListener('click', window.event)
  },
  unbind: function (el) {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', window.event)
  }
})

export default{
  name: 'Years',
  data() {
    return {
      show: false
    }
  },
  methods:{
    close: function(){
      this.show = false
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div id="years" v-show="show" v-click-outside="close">
  <!-- Years listed here... -->
  </div>
</template>
```

The `close` method is firing appropriately when I click outside of the `Years` component, but the problem is that I can't ever open the `Years` menu to begin with because clicking the button **also** fires the `close` behavior because it's **also** outside of the Years component.

Has anyone overcome this problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
...
methods:{
  clickYears: function(event){
    this.$refs.Years.show = true
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
...
```

Comment: You, my friend, are a genius. So I guess this stops the event from propagating all they way up to the `close` event listener that's on the `body` element. Very nice. Thank you!

Comment: Actually it prevents propagating close event to the btn. see more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation